# When and how is it safe to perform a system update?

Tags: updates

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Should I update it or leave it like that?

I ask, because the last time I had installed Ubuntu and updated it, I started facing errors like `System Program Problem Detected` and internal errors.

So, it is recommended to update it?

If yes, what is the safest method to do so? Is it by using Ubuntu's Update Manager or using the terminal. If by terminal, please tell me the commands to accomplish this.

Comment: What about custom config. I want to update my ubuntu as well but I am worried about, grub configuration (I had to adjust the text size as I have a hidpi monitor), special hardware as I have a dell XPS 15, nice machine but there was a tonne of stuff I had to fiddle with to get working. Also will my dual boot with windows 10 survive the update? I am worried about loosing my machine

Answer (score 6):

Updating is Highly advised , since newer version **Fixes bugs**, brings **New Features** , provides **Stability**. Upgrading **Kernel** provides better **support for your hardware and performance too**.

And **Security updates** are important to keep your Ubuntu secure.

**`One way`** : Use **Update Manager** to update your system .It will classify list updates under categories as **Important Security Updates** , **Recommended Updates** and **Other Updates** `( eg. PPA's)`

**`Second way`** : through **terminal**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This would be the best way to update your Ubuntu

Also if you want to upgrade your kernel , do it after the above process through

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or combining all above ,as All-in-one command.

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You can see the [Ubuntu security notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) here listing fixed vulnerabilities through updates , resolved mostly through security and other updates.

example : [Fixing bugs through updates](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-1509-2/).

Comment: Has anyone update their distro with the above mentioned command? This one:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Just wondering if it is 100% safe or it sometimes causes errors and conflicts.